# TypeScript error when using discriminated union type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use discriminated union type in TypeScript but I'm getting the following error:

```
Type '{ data: Aaaa | Bbbb; type: "aaaa" | "bbbb"; }' is not assignable to type 'EventData'.
  Type '{ data: Aaaa | Bbbb; type: "aaaa" | "bbbb"; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "bbbb"; data: Bbbb; }'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"aaaa" | "bbbb"' is not assignable to type '"bbbb"'.
        Type '"aaaa"' is not assignable to type '"bbbb"'.
```

With the following code:

```js
export type Aaaa = {
    aPropForA: string
}

export type Bbbb = {
    somePropsB: number
}

export type EventData =
  | { type: 'aaaa'; data: Aaaa }
  | { type: 'bbbb'; data: Bbbb }

// simulate getting the data for brevity
declare const data: EventData['data'];
declare const type: EventData['type'];

export const getEventData = (): EventData => {
  return { // why is there an error?
    data,
    type,
  }
}
```

[live](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBDLcC8cDeAUHCXBgApQRgBi0aAXHAM4xQCWAdgOaEC+hQqEiwEyVACEARjNwFipZhAC2wStWYSmnAK7KpwKP0HDo8JCjgBRAG7BOMACIYYGXAoA+BMSiYByLCw-AG44ABMXDCZMbAESL3wfYH8ZGRDwyKZpWQFCAHo8lnZlHQAbF1RuYBgYLm4EAAtUCNc4ADNoOCkoYBt2JEIw4ABjcp64YYhOVgzXJlt7J0iAbT8WjD8AXWDBkbHUSenzcXm7B2dXVYtgLZ2hcDMJqZmqmAXzyLkACgBKU8WLm4cAA+eQkHowHRQTjeApwADuDUQcHYzEahlQGBhhioUAA-AoSOsADSEpKkkgCARAA)

What's the source of the problem? How can I fix it without typecasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is an error is that nothing guarantees that the combination of `data` and `type` is correct. In this code, the assignments are valid, and would lead to an incorrect union:

```
const data: EventData['data'] = { aPropForA: ""};
const type: EventData['type'] = "bbbb"

export const getEventData = (): EventData => {
  return { // why is there an error?
    data,
    type,
  }
}
```

The only way to get around the error without type assertions is to make the required checks:

```
declare const data: EventData['data'];
declare const type: EventData['type'];

export const getEventData = (): EventData => {
  if(type === 'aaaa' && 'aPropForA' in data) {
    return { data, type,}
  } else if(type === 'bbbb' && 'somePropsB' in data) { 
    return { data, type,}
  }
  throw new Error("Invalid combination")
}
```

Comment: It… actually makes sense :) Thanks!